# Angular 7 CustomValidator never valid

Tags: angular, angular-validation

I know it could be a possible duplicate but the duplicate wasn't helping me because my validator isn't set on `FormGroup` level. The validator works. The `res` variable gives me a `true` when a username is already taken and `false` when not.

The Validator class:

```js
    @Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
    export class AlreadyTakenValidator {

        static checkUsername(registrationService: RegistrationService) {
            return (control: AbstractControl) => {
                if (control.value == "") {
                    return null;
                }
                console.log(control.value)
                return registrationService.checkUsername(control.value).subscribe(res => {
                    console.log("ab " + res)
                    if(res) {
                        const usernameIsTaken = true;
                        console.log("usernameIsTaken " + usernameIsTaken)
                        return (usernameIsTaken);

                    } else {
                        console.log("bischt null kerle?" + res)
                        const usernameIsTaken = null;
                        console.log("usernameIsTaken " + usernameIsTaken)
                        return usernameIsTaken;
                    }

                    return res ? { usernameIsTaken: true } : null;
                });
            }
        }
```

I just did that like this to check everything. Normally the last line `return res ? { usernameIsTaken: true } : null;` should be enough.

My TS:

```js
    public buildForm() {
        this.registerForm = this.form.group({
          username: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(this.minLength), CustomValidators.validateCharacters, AlreadyTakenValidator.checkUsername(this.registrationService)]],
          email: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.email, CustomValidators.validateCharacters]],
          password: ['', [Validators.required]],
          passwordConfirmation: ['', Validators.required],
        }, {
            validator: MustMatch('password', 'passwordConfirmation')
          });

        this.personalForm = this.form.group({
          firstname: ['', [Validators.required, NoWhitespaceValidator()]],
          lastname: ['', [Validators.required, NoWhitespaceValidator()]],
          country: ['', [Validators.required]],
          dateOfBirth: ['', [Validators.required]],
          gender: ['', [Validators.required]],
        })
      }
```

`AlreadyTakenValidator.checkUsername(this.registrationService)` is the problem.

In the html I just call:

```html
          <mat-error class="invalid-feedback"
            *ngIf="f.username.touched && f.username.errors && f.username.errors.usernameIsTaken">
            Already taken
          </mat-error>
          <mat-error class="invalid-feedback"
            *ngIf="f.username.touched && f.username.errors && f.username.errors.required">
            {{ 'REGISTRATION.USERNAME' | translate }} {{ 'VALIDATION.REQUIRED' | translate }}
          </mat-error>
          <mat-error class="invalid-feedback"
            *ngIf="f.username.touched && f.username.errors && f.username.errors.minlength">
            {{ 'VALIDATION.MINLENGTH' | translate }} {{ minLength }}
          </mat-error>
          <mat-error class="invalid-feedback"
            *ngIf="f.username.touched && f.username.errors && f.username.errors.invalid_characters">
            {{ 'VALIDATION.CHARACTERS' | translate }}
```

Also my `CustomValidators.validateCharacters` validator is custom like the name says and works fine, but this one isn't.

Comment: Would be simpler to have a repro with stackblitz to help you debug it ;)

Answer (score 0):

component.ts code

```
  checkUsername(control: AbstractControl) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    if (control.value === 'super@secret.com') {
        resolve({ emailIsTaken: true })
    } else {resolve(null)}
  }, 2000)
 })
}
```

component.html Code:

```
<form [formGroup]="form">
<input type="text" placeholder="Enter your email" formControlName="email"/>
<button type="submit" [disabled]="form.invalid">SEND</button>
<div *ngIf="form.get('email').pending">
<p>Form valid {{form.valid}}</p>
<p>Form invalid {{form.invalid}}</p> 
</form>
```

please change like wise in your code this is demo code

Comment: He only net to validate using AbstractControl without using promises, I dont understand why you have to use promises in this case ?